# Count arrows in string

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, algorithm, data-structures

I am trying to write the code to count arrows in string. I successfully run it and it works.

Arrow is like this `>>--> or <--<<` both has to take in account, also we have to take in account the shared part of arrows for example if i have `<--<<--<<` will give a count of 2 arrows.

My code to solve problem is this :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace StringsArrows
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (StreamReader reader = File.OpenText("C:\\Users\\Mohit\\Desktop\\PolmStudio Tasks\\StringsArrows\\StringsArrows\\File.txt"))
                 while (!reader.EndOfStream)
                 {
                     List<string> list = null;
                     string line = reader.ReadLine();
                     if (null != line)
                     {
                         list = new List<string>();
                         string[] digits = line.Split(new char[] {'\n' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
                         int counter = 0;
                         foreach (string word in digits)
                         {
                             for (int i = 0; i < word.Count();i++)
                             {
                                 if (i + 4 < word.Length)
                                 {
                                     if (word[i] == '<')
                                     {
                                         if (word[i + 1] == '-')
                                         {
                                             if (word[i + 2] == '-')
                                             {
                                                 if (word[i + 3] == '<')
                                                 {
                                                     if (word[i + 4] == '<')
                                                     {
                                                         counter++;
                                                     }
                                                 }
                                             }
                                         }
                                     }
                                     if (word[i] == '>')
                                     {
                                         if (word[i + 1] == '>')
                                         {
                                             if (word[i + 2] == '-')
                                             {
                                                 if (word[i + 3] == '-')
                                                 {
                                                     if (word[i + 4] == '>')
                                                     {
                                                         counter++;
                                                     }
                                                 }
                                             }
                                         }
                                     }
                                 }
                             }
                         }
                         Console.WriteLine(" Num. Of arrows are :"+counter);
                     }
                 }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

And input from file is this :

```
<--<<--<<
<<>>--><--<<--<<>>>--><
<-->>
```

It's output is this :

```
Num. Of arrows are :2
Num. Of arrows are :4
Num. Of arrows are :0
```

**What i want is:** Could some one please know if there is any way possible more optimized then this ?

Comment: The format of this question may be better suited for [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions) since it already works.

Comment: Since these are regular patterns have you considered a while loop and [`String.IndexOf(">>-->")`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k8b1470s(v=vs.110).aspx).  It returns the index of the first occurrence of the pattern.  You could search all cases.

Comment: As you may notice should you return to this question, there's a fair amount of controversy over the rules you stated and how they compare to the answers below. Please can you review and clarify the situation. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I do personally like loop-based solutions quite a lot (although you should improve your algorithm to reduce the big indentations;  via functions/recursivity). But in this specific case, there are much easier and efficient solutions; for example: relying on `Split`, which allows to easily determine the number of times that certain substrings are repeated.

Sample code:

```
string input = "<<>>--><--<<--<<>>>--><";

string[] temp = input.Split(new string[] { ">>-->", "<--<<" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
int totArrows = temp.Length - 1;
temp = input.Split(new string[] { ">>-->>-->", "<--<<--<<" }, StringSplitOptions.None);

totArrows = totArrows + temp.Length - 1; //4
```

UPDATE

As proven via comments, the proposed approach might not deliver the right answer under specific conditions. Also as explained via comments, my intention wasn't ever building a ready-to-use code perfectly addressing all the OP's concerns; but showing a different way to face the problem and setting a solid enough starting point (virtually a final solution).

In any case, for the sake of completeness (to reward the interest via comments) and to show the multiple applications of the proposed `Split` approach, below these lines I am including a different algorithm perfectly fulfilling (what seems to be) the OP's requirements.

```
string input2 = "<<>>--><--<<--<<>>>--><";

string[] temp2 = input2.Split(new string[] { "--" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
int totArrows2 = 0;

for(int i = 0; i < temp2.Length - 1; i++)
{
    string prevBit = temp2[i].Trim();
    string curBit = temp2[i + 1].Trim();

    if (prevBit.Length > 0 && curBit.Length > 0)
    {
        if (prevBit.Substring(prevBit.Length - 1, 1) == "<")
        {
            if (curBit.Length >= 2 && curBit.Substring(0, 2) == "<<") totArrows2 = totArrows2 + 1;
        }
        else if (prevBit.Length >= 2 && prevBit.Substring(prevBit.Length - 2, 2) == ">>")
        {
            if (curBit.Substring(0, 1) == ">") totArrows2 = totArrows2 + 1;
        }
    }
}

//totArrows2 = 4
```

Comment: This does not conform to OPs requirements. Counts 1 for `>-->`. That ain't right.

Comment: Quoting OP : "Arrow is like this `>>-->` or `<--<<`"

Comment: @spender OK, my bad, sorry about the mispelling. And such a tiny thing requires a downvote?! Seriously? Can you please remove your downvote now?

Comment: No, because this answer is incorrect according to opening sentence of OPs question. Your edit simply compounds the issue.

Comment: Obviously not. My bad.

Comment: As I understood the question, the arrow should be `<--<<` then optionally more `--<<`. I still don't get how this is right.

Comment: I remove DVs too, so don't be too worried. I'm still not a happy bunny though.

Comment: This marked as an accepted answer but  "<--<<--<<" returns 1 and question stated the should be 2.

Comment: @spender Firstly, you were right and I have corrected my mistake (I focused on the samples, rather than on the whole definition). Secondly, you can downvote what you wish, but what would be the point? Why not telling me about the problem when it is clearly something I didn't realise about?. And most importantly: I don't expect my codes to perfectly solve OPs' concerns at all the levels; although I do try to perfectly fullfil the specific requirements, my main intention is delivering a good approach which they are expected to adapt to their exact conditions.

Comment: @spender Done :) (was talking care of it while you were writing).

Comment: Still counts 1 for `<--<`. Really.

Comment: @spender Thisis  what is delivered under not-ideal correcting conditions (-> my suggestion of not downvoting so easily). Is it OK like this?

Comment: Nope :) Now it counts 1 for `--<<`

Comment: @spender I think that now it works exactly as expected. In any case, I want to insist in the fact that I just proposed a notably better approach without analysing the problem in detail. I don't like very simplified codes, but this situation certainly called for it. As said, if the approach I propose doesn't fully deliver the exact performance expected by the OP, he should adapt it (e.g., complement it with additional conditions or loops). Anyway... feel free to let me know if there is any other problem with my answer (I know the problem with yours: it is much slower :)).

Comment: According to the rules in the OPs question, the following string `>>-->>-->>-->>-->` should yield a result of 4 (you would count 3 with your latest edit). While I can't comment on speed or efficiency, isn't correctness more important?

Comment: @spender Much more important, no doubt on that. Also the amount of code is irrelevant. As said, the initial intention of my answer was providing some insights into how to solve the problem differently. The whole evolution of this conversation has made me deliver a result different than what is usual in me (= shorter, quicker but not working perfectly). I guess that the OP hasn't complained because his inputs do not have so extreme conditions (i.e., more focused on what is less evident at first sight, but easier for my approach). In any case and for shake of completeness, I will fix it...

Comment: As the accepted answer, you have a duty :) Good luck!

Comment: ... even though it might imply to somehow affect the .Split only approach which I have tried to maintain.

Comment: @spender I don't need luck. If I have to create an algorithm delivering a functionality, I do it. If maintaining the proposed Split approach is not acceptable to fully deliver all the functionalities, I would complement it with a different one.

Comment: @spender  Right or wrong the OP has accepted the answer.  Until the OP steps in we don't know if the question was misstated.

Comment: @fjardon Why? It is very easy. I have found problems by trying to be faithful to a given format, by not analysing the conditions properly and by getting involved in a quite unpractical discussion (-> not what anyone should do while creating an algorithm). But this is not a difficult implementation. The `Split` simplifies the problem a lot and then you have to account a few boundaries cases. Easy.

Comment: @spender After trying for a while, I realised that fully delivering what is expected was very difficult with my original approach, so I changed it. This is only slightly slower (still much faster than yours :)), very clear, scalable, etc. This is the way in which I would solve this problem (if I would have analysed it properly and not tried to make a given solution to work no matter what). I hope that my current tiredness didn't provoke any mistake (seriously, appreciate the contributions, but have been a bit tiring chat :)), otherwise, I will fix it tomorrow.

Answer (score 3):

To satisfy all your rules, running this Regex over each line and counting the number of times group `a` is matched

```
var pattern = "((?<a><--<<)(?<a>--<<)*)|((?<a>>>--)*(?<a>>>-->))";
var counts = lines.Select(line => Regex.Matches(line,pattern)
                                       .Cast<Match>()
                                       .Sum(m=>m.Groups["a"].Captures.Count));
```

gives you an `IEnumerable<int>` of `2, 4, 0`.

Answer (score 3):

This is good task for [finite state automaton (machine)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine) - FSA, FSM. You can enumerate states as positive numbers for right arrows and negative numbers for left arrows.
States 1, 2, 3, 4 correspond to sequences `> ,  >> ,  >>-, >>--`.

*Correction - I considered arrow with 1 '-'*

You just walk through string from left to right, and FSA changes it's state according to current state and current char. For example, for state 4 you have transition table

```
'>'  ..   1 (and increment arrow count)
'-'  ..   0
'<'  ..  -1
```

Time complexity is the best possible O(N) (you read each symbol just once).

Delphi code (`case` operator is close to `switch` with implicit break)

```
  function CountArrows(const s: string): Integer;
  var
    State, i: Integer;
  begin
    State := 0;
    Result := 0;
    for i := 1 to Length(s) do
      case s[i] of

        '-':
          case State of
            2, 3: State := State + 1;
            -1, -2: State := State - 1;
            -4: State := -2;
          else State := 0;
          end;

        '<':
          case State of
            - 3: State := -4;
            - 4: begin State := -1; Inc(Result); end;
          else State := -1;
          end;

        '>':
          case State of
            1, 2: State := 2;
            4: begin State := 1; Inc(Result); end;
          else State := 1;
          end;

      else //other symbol
        State := 0;
      end;

  end;
```

Comment: The theory is sound but the implementation is tricky. Computing the transitions by hand is not *that* simple. You also want to classify characters in 4 categories: *<*, *>*, *-*, *other* in order to reduce the transitions table size. All in all, I expect the code to be pretty messy... Unless you can prove me wrong, I'd like it :)

Comment: I count 11 states, and not too many transition arrows (not counting "other", which always takes you back to the initial state). Two transitions increment the number of arrows seen. Pretty simple, but you do need an FSA implementation to use it.

Answer (score 1):

check the following function :

```
 public int CountArrow(String main)
    {
        int result = 0;
        try
        {
            String arrow1 = ">>-->";
            String arrow2 = "<--<<";
            for (int i = 0; i < main.Length; i++)
            {
                if (main.IndexOf(arrow1,i) == i)
                    result++;
                if (main.IndexOf(arrow2,i) == i)
                    result++;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
        }
        return result;
    }
```

As and example:

```
CountArrow("<--<<--<<");
CountArrow("<<>>--><--<<--<<>>>--><");
CountArrow("<-->>");
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple one-liner:

```
string[] arrows = new[] { ">>-->", "<--<<" };

var count = Enumerable.Range(0, source.Length - 4).Count(i =>
    "><".Contains(s[i]) && arrows.Contains(source.Substring(i, 5)));
```

The above code iterates over all indexes of the source string at which an arrow might start. It checks whether the character at each index qualifies as the first character of an arrow, and if so, checks whether the entire 5-character sequence commencing at that index matches an arrow.

The first-character check is technically redundant, but saves you from creating a heap of string instances for the substrings.